# Partial Match Search Takes More time in MarkLogic

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine, marklogic

When i do partial match search instead of exact term match search, it takes more time than usual. I believe it generates more resultsets and compare with in it for partial search. How do i improve the performance of partial match search?

Ex: My Search Term : World Forum

If Marklogic Dictionary contains "World Economic Forum" as a term, it has to come as my result.

Comment: In addition to the remarks by Eric, it would be helpful to know the exact statement you use to do the search. Are you using cts:search or search:search? And with what options for instance..

Answer (score 0):

In general, response times are related to the # of matching documents.  So if you query is slow, someone will need to know more about your data, index settings, and query itself to help you.